# Keeping Command Buttons in the same relative position

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has 5 tables stacked on top of one another. Next to each table is a command button. These tables are all dynamic and have new rows being added/deleted.

How can I make it so that the command buttons stay right next to each respective table?

So far this is all I came up with, but this makes it so the command button is right under the headers and in the table.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim arr() As Variant
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("laborot").DataBodyRange


   With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton2")
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Left = rng.Left
        .Width = rng.Width
    End With
```

Comment: `.Left = rng.Left + rng.Width`  If you want the button to the right of the table.  If not, then where should it be?

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, I'm sorr I didn't even realize and I am clicking accept now!

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks you have been incredibly helpful!